# What does a bang symbol do in a data type?

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and today I read though the OpenGL source code and I found this

```
data VertexArrayDescriptor a =
   VertexArrayDescriptor !NumComponents !DataType !Stride !(Ptr a)
   deriving ( Eq, Ord, Show )
```

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/OpenGL-2.9.1.0/docs/src/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-GL-VertexArrays.html#VertexArrayDescriptor

I tried to search for it and found http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/bang-patterns.html but it is probably something different.

What does it do? What is it for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is to make it easier to write strict programs in Haskell and makes strictness more convenient for the developer to avoid being forced into being 'lazy' or non-strict just for convenience.

Take for example :

```
> data PNat = PZero | PSuc !Nat deriving Show
```

The bang declares that `PSuc` is strict in its argument, i.e. PSuc bottom = bottom (where bottom is a non-terminating expression).

It is to indicate strictness in patterns:

```
f !x !y = x + y
```

Good Reference : https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/BangPatterns

Comment: FWIW, the bang pattern forces the evaluation of the first constructor ([WHNF](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Weak_head_normal_form)). To fully force the evaluation of the structure check [`deepseq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq)

Comment: Your answer mixes Bang Patterns and [Strictness Flags](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-710004.2.1)